# Are there caveats to not using the spring-boot classloader in production?

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, classloading

### what

I would like to use `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader` instead of spring-boots `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader`. However, I am uncertain of the implications of how this will affect the spring-boot runtime.

### why

We recently ran into a `java.lang.InstantiationError` when making Spring repository calls inside java's `parallelStream()`. I learned that threads in the parallel stream are using the `AppClassLoader` and thus are unable to find the application classes residing in `LaunchedURLClassLoader`, a child of `AppClassLoader` in the classloader hierarchy.

### how

The [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-exploded-archives) shows you can run an unpacked spring-boot jar without using their classloader. This conveniently means that application classes are also loaded into `AppClassLoader`, resolving our issue with the `parallelStream()`.

```sh
$ java -cp BOOT-INF/classes:BOOT-INF/lib/* com.example.MyApplication
```

**NB**: This is also how Intellij IDEA runs spring-boot applications.

### question

Who knows if the spring-boot classloader is doing more than enabling executable jar and war files that I should know about. I found the documentation not explicit enough. Is it safe to **not** use spring-boot classloader in production?

Comment: Don't. You are fixing the problem in the wrong way. Also you should also be cautious when using `parallelStream` as it might block quite easily your whole system.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for pointing that out, I agree. This will be done in time. I would still like someone to answer my question about spring-boot classloading.

Comment: I sincerly doubt the issue is related to it, although it might solve it imho it is a symptom of something else.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Would you expect parallelStream() threads (from the ForkJoinPool) to use the spring-boot classloader, but something else is preventing that? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I would expect the correct classloader to be used (the current one, and reset afterwards). There have been some bugs (like [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172726) and others linked in that one) not properly setting or cleaning up the classloader. So either you are running with an old JDK without the patches, or you are doing things in your code you shouldn't be doing. In general it should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I also had intermittent issues with AppClassLoader being suddenly used instead of LaunchedURLClassLoader (even outside of parallel execution), leading to resources not being found.*

The latest version of the documentation has a [Efficient deployments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment.efficient) section  that says it is faster to run the unpacked archive.

> Certain PaaS implementations may also choose to unpack archives before they run. For example, Cloud Foundry operates this way.

Knowing that, I could say it's absolutely **safe to do it in production**.
I'd even say that it's safer, as it will be simpler at runtime, but it's my humble opinion.

> Once you have unpacked the jar file, you can also get an extra boost to startup time by running the app with its "natural" main method [...]:

```
$ jar -xf myapp.jar
$ java -cp "BOOT-INF/classes:BOOT-INF/lib/*" com.example.MyApplication
```

On Windows, replace `:` by `;` in casspath:

```
> java -cp "BOOT-INF/classes;BOOT-INF/lib/*" com.example.MyApplication
```

As you said, it conveniently means that we get rid of Spring Boot's custom `LaunchedURLClassLoader` as everything is loaded by `AppClassLoader`!

You can now use ForkJoinPool (`parallel()`, etc.) without ClassLoader issues:

```
[main] Test : CCL: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2a139a55
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Test  : CompletableFuture.runAsync CCL: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2a139a55
```

---

**Warning - there's only one note:**

> Using the JarLauncher over the application’s main method has the added benefit of a predictable classpath order. The jar contains a classpath.idx file which is used by the JarLauncher when constructing the classpath.

It means that running the exploded archive with JarLauncher instead of LaunchedURLClassLoader is safe and consistent because you keep the same classpath order. But JarLauncher launches the LaunchedURLClassLoader, so it does not solve our issue.

So beware of unpredictable classpath order when using the "natural" main method. It seems to be the only disadvantage.

*Personally, I did not have any issue with classpath ordering.*

Read:

- [Ensure consistent ordering of jars on classpath #7](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/spring-boot-cnb/issues/7)
- [Use the same
  classpath ordering for an exploded jar and an archive #9128](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9128)

---

Going further:

Looking at [LaunchedURLClassLoader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-classic/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.java), which extends [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html), and analyzing tests in [LaunchedURLClassLoaderTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-classic/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoaderTests.java) I can say that it simply adds logic that deals with JAR resource loading and nested JARs. There have been performance issues like [#4582](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/4582) that have been fixed in the past by adding the "fast exception" mechanism.

Comment: Wow, after 4 years an actual answer arrives! Interesting that this bit about improved startup time was added to the docs in the next minor version (2.2.x), while [we were using 2.1.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment) at the time. Of course we used the unpacked version and all was fine, like you mentioned, Patrice. Unknowingly, even enjoyed boosted startup!