# contextClassLoader unexpectedly changed on async methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

During scheduled job executions, some ClassPathResources are not found during some async task executions (while other tasks running at the same time find the same template).

After adding some traces, I found that when the problem occurs, the current thread's ClassLoader is not the same as usual:

- `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader`: resource
  found, OK
- `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`: resource **not** found, problem occurs

Here is the output of getting the ClassLoader on the Spring singleton bean providing the async mail sending method, in the catch block where the problem occurs:

```
getClass().getClassLoader(): org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@17a7cec2
currentThread().getContextClassLoader(): jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5cb0d902
ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader(): jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5cb0d902
ClassPathResource.getClassLoader(): jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5cb0d902
```

The question was: why someday the classloader is not Spring's LaunchedURLClassLoader anymore, but switches to JDK internal's AppClassLoader?

**Then how can we ensure that the same ClassLoader (here LaunchedURLClassLoader) will always be used, on all new threads?**

In my case, it occurs on `@Retryable @Async` methods launched by `@Scheduled` tasks.

If anyone got the same kind of issue, I'd be glad to hear how you dealth with it.

Problem occurs with OpenJDK 17, Spring Boot 2.7.17 (Spring Framework 5.3.30).

Using Spring Boot defaults, `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableAsync` and `@EnableRetry`

---

EDIT: issue relating to ForkJoin pool:

- [JDK-8184335: Release Note: Fork/Join common pool threads return the system class loader as their thread context class loader](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8184335)
- [SO: CompletableFuture / ForkJoinPool Set Class Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113207/completablefuture-forkjoinpool-set-class-loader)
- [Spring Boot: Java 11 and ForkJoinPool.commonPool() class loading issue #15737](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15737)
- [Spring Boot: Asynchronous deserialization performed by Hazelcast may fail due to the wrong ClassLoader being used #24836](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24836)

Comment: I don't know how this interacts with ClassPathResource and spring. In vanilla java, the _right_ way to do this stuff is `SomeClass.class.getResource`. __not__ `getClass()` (because that breaks when you subclass), __not__ `SomeClass.class.getClassLoader()` (it's pointless code, and dangerous: In exotic situations, that's `null` and causes an NPE). This ensures the loader used is the one that has loaded `SomeClass.class`. Which you know and control, so you can be certain the resource WILL be found then.

Comment: If I were to design a framework, the API would be `void loadResource(Class<?> context, String resourceName)` - and somewhere in that code, `context.getResource(mappedResourceName)` would be in there. Possibly the designers of this part of spring aren't as bad as this question makes it seem and you can find some API call that works in that (correct) fashion.

Comment: I'm not in control of resource loading here as it's done by Thymeleaf, which uses SpringResourceTemplateResource, which uses applicationContext.getResource(location).

Comment: may be a bug in any of the libraries involved. Not sure if anyone will be able to help here.

Comment: thread creation with contextclassloader selection being ultimately JRE's responsibility, I wonder why one day a thread gets created with another contextClassLoader. It would mean that its parent thread is not the same as the one launching other threads... after digging, I still don't understand how Spring can be involved in this issue.

Comment: possible workaround to ret rid of LaunchedURLClassLoader: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746223/are-there-caveats-to-not-using-the-spring-boot-classloader-in-production/77639527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem rose after the addition of a new scheduled job which uses a parallel stream, ultimately launching async tasks in its terminal forEach.

Threads created by ForkJoinPool (with AppClassLoader as the context class loader according to JDK-8184335) eventually add new threads for async task execution using the ThreadPoolExecutor.

As these threads might be reused, subsequent async tasks triggered by the application run on these threads, causing some tasks to fail because of the wrong contextClassLoader on the thread.

Alternative solutions:

- Isolate the parallel stream so it does not create reusable threads (by not launching `@Async` methods using the shared ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) - thus ensuring that all threads created for async method execution have LaunchedURLClassLoader as a contextClassLoader
- Explode the JAR and launch the application using its "natural" main method instead of executing the JAR, to get rid of LaunchedURLClassLoader (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77639527/1458562)